# php ftp download files with specific file extension

Tags: php, ftp, download

I try to figure out how to download files over ftp by php with a specific (*.opd) file
extension. There are other files with other extensions in the directory as well.

How do I scan the directory and retrieve all the files with an particular extension?

Thanks!

Nick

Comment: there is no question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have time to code this and test it so here's a skeleton.

Use PHP's [FTP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) to retrieve a list of files in the directory, then pick the ones you want and get them...

```
<?php

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// get contents of the current directory
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");

foreach ($contents as $filename) {
    if ($filename=='something.opd') { //insert whatever test you want here
        ftp_get($conn_id, $filename, $filename, FTP_BINARY)
}
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Note: this is **not** production ready code. I haven't tested it, and at the very least you'll need to add some error checking in here.

Answer (score 0):

`ftp_get()` retrieves a remote file from the FTP server, and saves it into a local file.

More info on it:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php

To scan the directory you can use `scandir()` and loop through the returned array, downloading the ones that match the extension you want.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Comment: If you can use `scandir()` you can just use `copy()` - both will require an `ftp:` wrapper. If you're using `ftp_get()` you might as well use `ftp_nlist()`.